# String Literal Types union with string type

Tags: typescript

I want to use the intellisense of typescript on some predefined colors in my component's prop. But user can also pass any hex color into that prop too.

```
type PREDEFINED_COLORS = 'success' | 'error' | 'info';

type Props = {
   color: PREDEFINED_COLORS | string;
}
```

I know *PREDEFINED_COLORS* is also a *string* but i believe there should be some workarounds to achieve the benefits of intellisense.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you could prefix abritrary hex strings with `#` -> `color: PREDEFINED_COLORS | '#${string}'`

Comment: Type '"testColor"' is not assignable to type 'COLOR_MAP_TYPES | "#${string}" | undefined'

Comment: If you are interested in validating HEX strings, you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/hex-validation). Also, it is possible only with extra function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your safest bet would be to use a `templated string type`. Something like this:

```
type PREDEFINED_COLORS = 'success' | 'error' | 'info';

type Props = {
   color: PREDEFINED_COLORS | `#${string}`;
}
```

You may try to narrow the type even more, creating a hexDigit and then building the entire type from there. Something like this:

```
type hexDigit = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd' | 'e' | 'f'
type hexColor = `#${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}${hexDigit}`
```

The problem with this is that TS will generate the entire crossproduct of the `hexDigit` type and that will end up being a huge type. More exactly it will have 2^32 items which is way above the 100k limit they have. You can more about this [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33130).

Comment: I'm getting that error when trying with PREDEFINED_COLORS | `#${string}`;


Type '"ffffff"' is not assignable to type 'PREDEFINED_COLORS | `#${string}` | undefined'.ts(2322)

Comment: That's because there's and added # at the start of the string, this means that "ffffff" is not valid, but "#ffffff" is